# pdfpc Installation

Tags: 14.04, package-management, libraries

I have recently started to work with ubuntu and I have ubuntu 15.04 installed on my computer. This question for me is more than just how to install `pdfpc` but is also about learning how applications and libraries are connected to each other.
When I tried to install `pdfpc` from [here](http://davvil.github.io/pdfpc/) I realized that I need to install libraries such as `librsvg` beforehand. When I tried to install that from [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/librsvg.html) more dependencies started to show up. I realized that I need to install `libcroco` and to do that I also need to install `libxml`. Am I really on the right track or what? Is there a way to install a package where you install all its dependencies with it instead of having to do it separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you want to compile software yourself, then it is normal that other libraries are needed. Typically, these libraries are available for Ubuntu
2. If not, then start again with point 1 **=)**

For `pdfpc` you need `libPoppler` and `librsvg`. Therefore start a search in your system:

- `libPoppler`

  ```
  % apt-cache search --names-only '^libPoppler.*dev$'
  libpoppler-cpp-dev - PDF rendering library -- development files (CPP interface)
  libpoppler-dev - PDF rendering library -- development files
  libpoppler-glib-dev - PDF rendering library -- development files (GLib interface)
  libpoppler-private-dev - PDF rendering library -- private development files
  libpoppler-qt4-dev - PDF rendering library -- development files (Qt 4 interface)
  libpoppler-qt5-dev - PDF rendering library -- development files (Qt 5 interface)
  libpoppler-cil-dev - PDF rendering library -- CLI development files
  libpopplerkit-dev - GNUstep framework for rendering PDF content (development files)
  ```

  and I would say, `libpoppler-dev` is ok, therefore

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libpoppler-dev
  ```
- `librsvg`

  ```
  % apt-cache search --names-only '^librsvg.*dev$'   
  librsvg2-dev - SAX-based renderer library for SVG files (development)
  librsvg2-2.0-cil-dev - CLI binding for RSVG 2.22
  ```

  therefore

  ```
  sudo apt-get install librsvg2-dev
  ```

---

And now the test

```
mkdir -p ~/src
wget https://github.com/downloads/davvil/pdfpc/pdfpc-3.1.1.tgz
tar xf pdfpc-3.1.1.tgz -C ~/src
cd pdfpc-3.1.1
cmake .
```

and I see

```
--   package 'gee-1.0' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:344 (message):
  A required package was not found
```

Ok, another package is required

```
% apt-cache search --names-only '^libgee.*dev$'
libgee-0.8-dev - GObject based collection and utility library (development files)
libgee-dev - GObject based collection library (development files)
```

therefore

```
sudo apt-get install libgee-dev
```

and again

```
cmake .
```

Ups, another thing

```
-- checking for module 'poppler-glib'
--   package 'poppler-glib' not found
```

And again

```
% apt-cache search --names-only '^libpoppler.*glib.*dev$'
libpoppler-glib-dev - PDF rendering library -- development files (GLib interface)
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libpoppler-glib-dev
```

and again **o_O**

```
cmake .
```

And ... great **^_^**

```
-- checking for module 'poppler-glib'
--   found poppler-glib, version 0.30.0
-- checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
--   found gtk+-2.0, version 2.24.27
-- checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
--   found gthread-2.0, version 2.44.1
-- checking for module 'librsvg-2.0'
--   found librsvg-2.0, version 2.40.9
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/aboettger/tmp/pdfpc-3.1.1
```

Now let's start the compiler via `Makefile`

```
make
```

And after this install via

```
sudo make install
```

or better with `checkinstall`

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall
```

and we have `pdfpc` installed

```
% pdfpc
pdfpc v3.1.1
(C) 2012 David Vilar
(C) 2009-2011 Jakob Westhoff

Error: No pdf file given
```

And it works with the sample from the project page

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it was very helpful. I was finally able to install pdfpc. Can you explain how come I can add "lib" to the beginning and "-dev" to the end of the name of a package that is missing and use sudo apt-get install "libPackage-dev" and it will work while sudo apt-get install "Package" will not work! I want to learn the meaning of each prefix/suffix

Comment: That's the naming convention in Ubuntu, mostly :) sometimes it's a little bit try and error.

Comment: @AliJamali In my understanding, you need a *library* (hence `lib`) because that's what other software interfaces with; and you need the *developers version* (hence `dev`) because you're building from source.